# Use of “ in a state”

Tags: phrase-usage

Are sentences below correct? I just want to learn if use of "in a state" is correct or not. I know I can make this sentence without "in a state" but as told I just try to understand "in a state." I mean if I use "in a state" in this way, would it be grammatically correct?

> 1. I don't want him to see me in a state without makeup.
> 2. I don't want my photo to be taken in a state without makeup.
> 3. My photo was taken in a state in black suit. (Should I delete "in a state" in this sentence?)

Are all three correct?

Comment: In all three sentences, the phrase "in a state" makes them wordy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "state" means *the particular condition that someone or something is in at a specific time*.

In your first two examples, the "state" of the person is specified - they are "without makeup". The person does not want anyone to see/photograph them in that particular condition, at that time.

Your third example is not correct, for a few reasons. Firstly, although we can say someone is "in makeup" we do not say "in suit" - it would be "in *a* suit", and that isn't really a condition. There is a common expression "*in a state of undress*" which means either completely naked or partially dressed; however, we would not normally say "in a state in a suit".

Lastly, this may be a particularly *British* English idiom, but "in a state" can be used in isolation to mean "in a *bad* state", and is used in various ways. Someone might say "I'm in a state" to mean that their appearance or their home is untidy, or not as presentable as they would like.  It can also mean that someone is a poor *emotional state*, or that someone is in poor physical health.

Comment: I know those sound weird. But as far as I understood from what you said , If say such a sentence It wouldn’t be wrong but wouldn’t  be understood eaisly.

Comment: @languagelearner Like all languages, we have idioms - sometimes a phrase is acceptable in one context but not another. Your third example could be structually and grammatically correct if you add in the article "a" but it would not be idiomatic. The first two are fine, though.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: +1 I agree, but would go further and argue this is almost certainly the British idiom "in a state", which basically means "in a mess", either physically dishevelled as in this particular context, or an emotional wreck in other contexts.   There would be no need to say "in a state" under normal circumstances, unless it's actually the idiom that is being used here. The problem here I think is that the OP has seen example 1, and thought that the meaning was literal and has tried to use the literal meaning in other sentences not realising it's actually an idiom.

Answer (score 0):

In all three of your examples, "in a state" is not needed but in the first sentence its usage is not wrong. You'd generally use "in a state" when you have to specify that state in detail. For example 'He drove that car in a state where he could not control any aspect of his motor controls'. In your case, you could change the first sentence to "I don't want him to see me without makeup", which gives the same meaning. For the second sentence you could say "I don't want my photo to be taken in a state when I'm without makeup". For the third according to my understanding of your sentence, you'd have to change it to 'I wore a black suit when my photo was taken'.

Answer (score 0):

I think the phrase is more commonly used with the word *of* followed by a noun. So, for example, we might say:

> 1. When I found Liam on the side of the road, he was **in a state of confusion**.
> 2. My parents were **in a state of shock** after the house fire.
> 3. The house would not sell because it was **in a state of disrepair**.

Grammatically, you can often change the phrase to an adjectival form of the noun instead; for example:

> 1. When I found Liam on the side of the road, he was **confused**.
> 2. My parents were **shocked** after the house fire.

Some might say the meaning has shifted a little bit, as "in a state of confusion" seems a little deeper and more long-lasting than merely "being confused" – but that's not necessarily a given in all cases.

As for the third sentence in my trio of examples, you don't see the word "disrepaired" very often. Most likely, a synonym would be used instead:

> 3. The house would not sell because it was **dilapidated**.